# angularjs course registration app

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, registration

I'm making an app where you have a json list of courses with a title, course id, location and course type.

When you click on the course I'm getting a modal window to confirm registration for the selected course. It sends the info to a php file which gets the info back in json format to get feedback if you regsitered well.

I'm stuck at this point because angular doesn't seem to get the info back... when I use the console.log(data) I see the info that gets back from the php file.
But when I want to parse some of this info to the page it says "undifined"...

I would also be able to hide the registration button for users that were already registered for some courses, I should I do that?

Anyone a good example of something similar?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

My only guess, with nothing to go on, is that you are attempting to access the data before the callback is finished. You see the data in the console because when the data resolves, it shows up resolved in the console. Your function to get/send the data should have a callback function available, or should return a promise. When you include it in a template it should eventually resolve fine, but if you are trying to do any data manipulation in the JS itself you need to put all of it inside the callback or in `$promise.$then(function() {/*stuff here*/});`